# How can I transfer the char c[0] to int

Tags: c++, atoi

I read a file with getline, and want to transfer char c[0] to int, I got an error.

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
g[n].chicken = atoi(c[0]);
                       ^
```

In file included from assign.cpp:5:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:147:12: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘int atoi(const char*)’ [-fpermissive]
 extern int atoi (const char *__nptr)

```
 24        int g;
 25        string str;
 26        while(getline(file,str)){
 27           
 28           const char* ct = str.c_str();
 29           char c[5];
 30           strcpy(c,ct);
 31        
 32
 33           g = atoi(c[0]);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include a `main()` function and the `#include` statements, and then shrink your code to the smallest program possible that produces your problem. We call this a [mcve]. This allows members to copy, paste, compile, and then Help you.  Also, do not post linenumbers as they do not copy well.

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains what the parameter to `atoi()` should be, then look at the code above. The reason for the compilation error should be obvious. The parameter to `atoi()` is a `const char *`. The shown code is passing a `char` parameter. This is not allowed in C++. If a function takes a `const char *` parameter, then that's what you must pass to it, and not a `char`. This is literally what the error message says.

Comment: `atoi(c);` must be instead `atoi(c[0]);`

Comment: Are you trying to convert the whole string to a number or one digit? One digit is easy, `'0' + c[0]`, but it isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why not use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)? Why even have *two* temporary and otherwise unused variables (and risk buffer overflow as well)?

Comment: And if your file is only space-delimited (and newline is a space character) integers, why not `while (file >> g) { /* Use g... */ }`?

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of atoi looks like this:  `int atoi(const char* buffer)`

You need

```
g = atoi(c);
```

because c is the pointer to the character array.  The array c[5] consists of 5 bytes.  c[0] is the first byte.  c alone is interpreted by the compiler as a pointer to the first byte.

So, atoi() it takes a pointer to an array of characters.  You passed it the first character.

Using std::getline() to retrieve user input is a great idea.  Learn to use stringstream to parse items from the getline().  Once you get good at it, you will make fewer mistakes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
  int g;

  std::ifstream file;
  file.open ("example.txt");

  std::string str;
  while (getline(file, str)) {
    std::istringstream stream(str);

    stream >> g;

    std::cout << "g is " << g << std::endl;

  }
}
```